# Looping over a portion of non-sequential directories in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, xargs

Input txt file:
SAMN02354977
SAMN02355030
SAMN08154141

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "${line}.merged.markdup.recal.g.vcf.gz"
done < "$1"
```

command:

```
./idk.sh FramminghamSamples.txt > testing.txt
```

how can I stop it from returning:

```
SAMN02354977
.merged.markdup.recal.g.vcf.gz  
SAMN02355030
.merged.markdup.recal.g.vcf.gz  
SAMN08154141
.merged.markdup.recal.g.vcf.gz
```

This is because I will want run a command on each of the "$line".merged.markdup.recal.g.vcf.gz files that are in each of the $line directories.

#L2CodeNoob

(I also tried:

```
 #!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    echo "${line}.merged.markdup.recal.g.vcf.gz"
done < "$1"
```

)

Comment: Ok so I found somewhere to add:
/[$'\t\r\n ']
so that it would be:
echo "${line//[$'\t\r\n ']}.merged.markdup.recal.g.vcf.gz"

but what does /[$'\t\r\n '] mean?

Comment: `//[$'CHARS']` is special bash syntax for replacing all characters in the list `CHARS` with nothing. According to the manual page for bash describing pattern substitution the syntax is `${parameter/pattern/string}`, but "If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted." You can check https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash, specifically the Parameter Expansion and Pattern Matching sections for more details.